# Whats the closest thing to a Lua table operation in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, lua

Recently got C++ & SDL2 to compile, and started messing around. I've learned Lua and JavaScript pretty well, and can get most things I need to done in them with no issue.

I was hoping to create an object that achieves something like this Lua example, but in C++. I haven't been able to find anything online, but I'm probably not using the correct search terms, as I'm new to C++ (although I have some experience in C).

```
foo = {
    a = 0,
    b = "hello"
    c = "world"
}

function foo:bar(baz)
    self.a = self.a + 1
    print(self.b.." "..self.c)
    table.insert(self, baz)
end
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be easier to start learning C++ from [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282), instead of immediately trying to play with it on your own. C++ isn't as tolerant of mistakes as Lua is.

Still, here's some C++ code similar to your Lua example:

```cpp
// Makes the standard type std::string available:
#include <string>

// Every variable needs a type.
// "class" creates a new type with given members, so here's how we'll define
// a type for variable "foo".
// A class definition like this usually goes in a header file.
class FooType
{
  public:
    // These members have default initializers, which will be used when
    // a FooType object is created without its own initializer.
    int a = 0;
    std::string b = "hello";
    std::string c = "world";

    // This declares a class member function named bar, returning nothing:
    void bar();
};

// The actual variable foo:
FooType foo;

// Defining the member function called FooType::bar :
// This might go in a source file which begins with an #include of
// the corresponding header file.
#include <iostream> // to get std::cout and std::endl
void FooType::bar()
{
    // self.a = self.a + 1 :
    // The C++ keyword "this" is similar to Lua's "self", but is a pointer.
    // All of these are equivalent:
    // (*this).a = (*this).a + 1;
    // this->a = this->a + 1;
    // a = a + 1;  // C++ automatically adds an implicit "this->" when you
                   // just name a member.
    // ++a; // A shortcut for adding one to a number.
    ++a;

    // print(self.b.." "..self.c) :
    std::cout << b << " " << c << std::endl;
    // Lua's print automatically adds a newline after its data, but
    // C++ std::cout does not. The std::endl adds a newline and then
    // "flushes" the output, making sure it gets sent out more or less
    // immediately instead of waiting for more data as an optimization.

    // table.insert(self, baz) :
    // Not possible - C++ does not allow adding members to a class which
    // aren't declared in the class definition. If you really need something
    // similar, you could use a map with name as the key, but then you would
    // need to access all those "members" via that map, not with a plain
    // obj.name expression.
}
```

Some differences to note:

In Lua, the colon method syntax is just a shortcut. That is, `foo:bar(t)` is exactly the same as `foo.bar(foo, t)`, but Lua would let you do weird things like `foo.bar(0, t)` meaning the `self` variable becomes `0`. (This might of course violate the implied contract of the `bar` method!) In C++, compilers will often implement member functions as though they're ordinary functions with an extra parameter for `this`, but as far as the language is concerned, a member function is entirely different from a non-member function, and the only ways to call it all involve an object of the correct type to become `*this`.

Related, Lua lets you reassign `self`, but C++ does not let you change the pointer `this`.

Lua treats tables with "reference semantics", but the default in C++ is that all variables use "value semantics".

```lua
-- Lua:
foo2 = foo     -- Another name for the same table.
foo2.a = 3     -- foo.a is now 3.
```

```cpp
// C++ (within a function):
FooType foo2 = foo;  // A different independent object.
foo2.a = 3;          // foo2.a is 3, but foo.a is unchanged

FooType& foo3 = foo; // Another name for object foo.
foo3.a = 4;          // foo.a is now 4.
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at that list and grab a book on C++, all I really got right now is a rather *eh* library book that weighs more than my laptop. I really appreciate the line comments as well :D